# How to maintain session in android using an HttpClient

Tags: android, session

I am using an `HttpClient` to make server connection, like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/login");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
```

The server session works with **cookies**.

And to maintain session I have to use the same client for all the subsequent connections. Which I am doing and works fine.

But the problem is, in android usually Activity data is destroyed when there is a need, which destroys the `HttpClient` too (when my application is in baclground) and hence the session is being lost.

Is there a way to make a `HttpClient` persistent? Or how do I solve this case?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as I know to save your session and recreate after Activity relaunch.

The only one way is to put your `HttpClient`  code to Service. By this way you can play with activities and do not worry about broken sessions.

You can find  `Services` documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

> The server session works with cookies.

for Android by default cookies are enable  and you don't need to worry about.

For sure you can store Cookies but I don't see the reason that it can help you somehow for your question.

Anyways this is a technique to fetch Cookies:

```
List<Cookie> mCookies = null;

mCookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

        if (mCookies.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("test_runner", "Cookies: None");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mCookies.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("- " + mCookies.get(i).toString());
                Log.d("test_runner", "Cookies: [" + i + "]" + mCookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
```

And this is a way how to put them back:

```
 CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 

     for(Cookie cook : mCookies){
         cookieStore.addCookie(cook); 
     }

     httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
     httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to put all the function that your server do in on unique class which is going to be call by the tasks which want to connect. I call this class WebServiceManager. This class have exactly the same method than the server.

As you want an unique session do :

```
private static WebServiceManager wsm = null;

public static WebServiceManager getInstance() {
    if (wsm == null) {
        wsm = new WebServiceManager();
    }
    return wsm;
}

private final HttpClient httpClient;

private WebServiceManager() {
    httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
}
```

and then you call the method of your instance of webServiceManager to use always the same httpclient and you keep your cookies. :)